# How to replace part of URL correctly?

Tags: regex, sed

I want to replace a name of `txt` file located in `example.txt` file, whose content is

```
whatever http://example.com/t25.txt whatever whatever
whatever2
whatever
```

with another `txt` filename among random strings. The result of
`sed -i -E 's/\/(.*?)\.txt/b82/' example.txt` command is

```
whatever http:b82 whatever whatever
whatever
```

but I wanted

```
whatever http://example.com/b82.txt whatever whatever
whatever2
whatever
```

How can I do it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of non-greedy quantifiers (`*?`) with an overly broad character class (`.`, matching any character at all), be more precise: `[^/]*` will match 0 or more non-slash characters, which ensures that the match doesn't cross any `/` boundaries.

Also don't forget to add the matched parts that you don't want to change back in in the replacement part:

```
s!/[^/]*\.txt!/b82.txt!
```

I've switched to a different delimiter for `s` here (namely `!`) in order to avoid leaning toothpick syndrome (`/\/[^\/]...`).